# Read external text file in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, file, external, show

I need some help with the following code displaying external html file contents. It works but loads very slow.

I added the following code to the functions.php

```
  function show_file_func( $atts ) {
  extract( shortcode_atts( array(
    'file' => ''
  ), $atts ) );

  if ($file!='')
    return @file_get_contents($file);
}
add_shortcode( 'show_file', 'show_file_func' );
```

Then use the following shortcode to enter into a page referencing the file.

If there is an alternative or suggestion for the contents to load faster.. thanks.

Comment: if reading the webpage is too long, you can cache it with [set_transient](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/set_transient).

Comment: Thanks @kaperto - as set transient is included in wp-include/options.php I see the following - <?php
set_transient( 'special_query_results', $special_query_results, 12 * HOUR_IN_SECONDS );
?> where do I set this exactly..?